# Bash running multiple program and handling close

Tags: bash, shell-script, kill, background-process

I have a bash script that runs multiple programs

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
python program1.py &
python program2.py &
other programs ... &
lastProgram
```

I run it as `./myscript.sh`

When I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to close the `lastProgram` it exit and all the other ones keep running in the background. The problem is that the other programs need to be terminated.

Which is the proper way to handle the closing of all the programs started from the script?

Comment: You run the programs in background so you should handle the pids. Also you should handle the Ctrl+C and terminate the pids you collect before

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Collect the process ID's, kill the background processes on exit.

```
#!/bin/bash
killbg() {
        for p in "${pids[@]}" ; do
                kill "$p";
        done
}
trap killbg EXIT
pids=()
background job 1 & 
pids+=($!)
background job 2... & 
pids+=($!)
foreground job
```

Trapping `EXIT` runs the function when the shell exits, regardless of the reason. You could change that to `trap killbg SIGINT` to only run it on `^C`.

This doesn't check if one of the background processes exited before the script tries to shoot them. If they do, you could get errors, or worse, shoot the wrong process.

---

Or kill them by job id. Let's read the output of `jobs` to find out which ones are still active.

```
#!/bin/bash 
killjobs() {
    for x in $(jobs | awk -F '[][]' '{print $2}' ) ; do 
        kill %$x
    done
}
trap killjobs EXIT
sleep 999 &
sleep 1 &
sleep 999 &
sleep 30
```

If you run background processes that spawn other processes (like a subshell: `(sleep 1234 ; echo foo) &`), you need to enable job control with `set -m` ("monitor mode") for this to work. Otherwise just the lead process is terminated.

Comment: Your answer was extremely complete and didactic. I can now can run my project after closing it without having to check if any port "bind" was left behind. Thanks for your effort

Answer (score 3):

I was just reading similar questions about collecting PID's and then killing them all at the end of a script - the **problem** is that a PID for a finished process *could get recycled and re-used in a new process* before your script finishes, and then you could **kill a new (random) process**.

## Trap EXIT and kill with bash's job control

You could use bash's job control to only kill processes started in the script with a trap and %n jobspec, counting the max number of jobs that could be running (only 3 in this example):

```
#!/bin/bash
#trap 'kill %1 %2 %3' 0     # 0 or EXIT are equivalent
#trap 'kill %1 %2 %3' EXIT  # or use {1..n} as below
trap 'kill %{1..3}' EXIT
sleep 33 &
sleep 33 &
sleep 33 &
echo processes are running, ctrl-c the next sleep
sleep 66
echo this line will never be executed
```

Any extra "kills" to non-existent jobspec's that have already finished only results in an error message, it won't kill any other new/random processes.

---

## kill your script's complete process group

Here's a slightly different way way to kill your script's complete process group. But if your script/shell's job control isn't set up then it *could* inherit it's PPID from it's parent... but without job control the above wouldn't work either.

The difference is this kill command for trap, using bash's PID, since it becomes the PGID for new processes:

```
trap 'kill -- -$$' EXIT
```

See [this related Q](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/139230/37589) or [here where Johannes 'fish' Ziemke traps SIGINT and SIGTERM and uses `setsid` to "*kill the complete process group in a new process group so we won't risk killing our selves*."](https://coderwall.com/p/q-ovnw/killing-all-child-processes-in-a-shell-script))

Comment: Good point about avoiding shooting recycled PIDs. I thought about killing by jobid, but didn't come up with a good way to collect them.

Comment: @ilkkachu 
I did find another way to kill the script's whole process group, it doesn't feel as "safe" as the jobspec method though. I considered parsing `jobs` too, then realized it doesn't matter if you try to kill already finished jobs, aside from an error message that can be `2>/dev/null`'d, if it's even noticed. They always start counting from one and have a maximum, so might as well just kill'em all (shoot first, no questions ;-)

Comment: ah, right, for a noninteractive shell (without job control) that works, though it does kill the shell itself too which may be annoying if you want to do something else after that. `jobs` and the `%1` jobid's do work on noninteractive shells too, it just doesn't put background jobs in separate process groups.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to kill all background processes if they do not complete before `lastProgram` has finished executing, you will need to store all of the pids:

```
python program1.py &
p1pid=$!
python program2.py &
p2pid=$!
other programs ... &
p3pid=$!
lastProgram

kill $p1pid $p2pid $p3pid
```

If you simply want to wait until all background processes have finished executing before exiting the script, you can use the `wait` command.

```
python program1.py &
python program2.py &
other programs ... &
lastProgram
wait
```

Comment: If program1.py has finished the process PID may be reused by another starting program. Therefore the kill $p1pid may kill a random process. Is this correct or there is any mechanism that avoids this?

Comment: @RicardMolins that collision is theoretical and not practical. SHA256 can technically have a collision, but we treat it as if it's not possible. Linux systems default to 4194304 PIDs.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my one line command (in `bash`):

```bsh
trap "jobs -p | xargs kill ; trap - INT" INT ; cmd1 & cmd2 & cmd3 &
# replace `cmds` with your command
```

What it does is trapping <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to kill all background jobs and revert back to its default behaviour.

Then, it runs all the commands in background.

When you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, it will kill them all and reset trap back to its default behaviour.