# Why are processes grouped by a PGID?

Tags: process, process-groups

I am interested why processes are grouped additionally while having already a PPID and PID. What's the advantage of process groups?

Comment: Relating in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139222/why-is-the-pgid-of-my-child-processes-not-the-pid-of-the-parent and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/404054/117549