# How do I run multiple processes with the same process group id?

Tags: process, kill, syscalls

I am learning how to use the killpg syscall. So for an experiment,  I want to start two new processes with the same pgid and then attempt to kill them using killpg.

I read about setsid so I tried something like:

```
setsid gedit & firefox &
```

But the two processes: gedit and firefox ended up having two different pgids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Firefox and a few tabs in it if you can. Then do this:

```
ps o pid,ppid,pgid,sid,comm
```

You should see something like this:

```
  PID  PPID  PGID   SID COMMAND
 5121 25145  2628  2628 Web Content
 5881 25145  2628  2628 Web Content
25145     1  2628  2628 firefox-esr
```

Or use a subshell to spawn background processes:

```
$ (sleep 100& gedit&)
$ ps o pid,ppid,pgid,sid,comm
  PID  PPID  PGID   SID COMMAND
 6365  2618  6364 27631 sleep
 6366  2618  6364 27631 gedit
```

Here's a good explanation why a subshell and what's going on: [Why is the PGID of my child processes not the PID of the parent?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/139230/181255)

Also see:

```
man credentials
```

Comment: ok, can i make gedit and firefox have the same pgid?

Comment: @alkabary See my update.